# Show character change count while editing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, editor

While editing the questions or answers of other people, why there is no characters change count?

This might be helpful to see whether I changed 6 characters while I am editing rather than knowing after submit.

Answer (score 3):

Meh, I don't think we should go there. This might encourage minor edits only to get the needed 6 characters. People already do that now, and it is not helping. Putting any more emphasis on this is bad in my opinion.

Also, for all other users, the change count doesn't matter. You change what you need to change, without looking at the number of changes.